# Emacs 9x15 fonts on Exceed/Linux

Tags: emacs, fonts

I'm used to 9x15 fonts in emacs, but since I switched to a 100dpi settings in my Exceed server I'm unable to load them. The emacs fonts menu only offers Liberation, Sans, Monospace and Serif for selection, but not the fixed size fonts I need.

xterm works fine. I can run it with any fixed size fonts I want, for example: 'xterm -fn 9x13'. If I try the same command with emacs, it comes up with another font. This is the output from the emacs describe-font command:

> name (opened by): -unknown-Liberation
>   Sans-normal-normal-normal-*-17-*-75-75-*-0-iso10646-1
>          full name: Liberation Sans:pixelsize=17:foundry=unknown:weight=normal:slant=normal:width=normal:dpi=75:scalable=true
>               size: 17
>             height: 20  baseline-offset:  0 relative-compose:  0

My configuration is:

Exceed Windows XServer version 14, window manager running on Windows. Emacs running on Linux 2.6.32 (Red Hat)

How can I force emacs to use 9x15 fonts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by manually editing .emacs custom-set-faces:

```
(custom-set-variables
  ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(blink-cursor-mode nil)
 '(default-frame-alist (quote ((menu-bar-lines . 1) (vertical-scroll-bars . right) (tool-bar-lines . 0))))
 '(scroll-bar-mode (quote right))
 '(show-paren-mode t)
 '(tool-bar-mode nil))
(custom-set-faces
  ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(default ((t (:inherit nil :stipple nil :background "#f0f0f0" :foreground "black" :inverse-video nil :box nil :strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil :style "Regular" :slant normal :weight normal :width normal :foundry "misc" :family "fixed" :height 130)))))
```

Emacs seems to use the fc-list convention to select the fonts. However the shift-B1 menu only displays fonts available on the local machine, *not* those available on the X server. This mismatch could be where the problem starts. In my case choosing the default font from the emacs menu didn't actually change my .emacs settings.

Also I tried to set pixelsize in the .emacs code to change the font size, but the only fc-list parameter that worked was height. Of course, each height value will look different on 75dpi and 100dpi server settings.