# How can I debug emacs23 fonts loading?

Tags: emacs, fonts

I want to use the same 9x15 fixed fonts that I have in my xterm in emacs but for some reason I can't load them when running emacs on Linux through a Windows X Server. This query to the X server shows the path of all available fonts:

```
# xset q|grep "program files"|tr ":" "\n"
c:/program files/hummingbird/connectivity/14.00/exceed/font/misc,c
c:/program files/hummingbird/connectivity/14.00/exceed/font/100dpi,c
c:/program files/hummingbird/connectivity/14.00/exceed/font/75dpi,c
c:/program files/hummingbird/connectivity/14.00/exceed/font/misc_utf8,c
c:/program files/hummingbird/connectivity/14.00/exceed/font/100dpi_utf8,c
c:/program files/hummingbird/connectivity/14.00/exceed/font/75dpi_utf8,c
c:/program files/hummingbird/connectivity/14.00/exceed/font/andrew,c
c:/program files/hummingbird/connectivity/14.00/exceed/font/pc,c
c:/program files/hummingbird/connectivity/14.00/exceed/font/hp,c
c:/program files/hummingbird/connectivity/14.00/exceed/font/dec100,c
c:/program files/hummingbird/connectivity/14.00/exceed/font/dec75,c
...

# xlsfonts|grep 9x15
9x15
9x15
9x15-l1
9x15b
9x15b-l1
9x15bold
9x15bold
```

Does emacs load fonts from the X server or it only checks some local server directory? How can I check which fonts emacs is loading and from where?

Comment: I was able to fix my 100dpi server fonts by manually editing my .emacs (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306406/emacs-9x15-fonts-on-exceed-linux). Still, it would be good to know how to trace emacs font selection.